# Derivating a polynomial equation from two others

Tags: polynomials, roots, differential

In an old article of J. Cockle, [Sketch of a Theory of Transcendental Roots](https://archive.org/details/londonedinburghd20lond/page/146/mode/1up), pages $146$/$147$, the author obtains an expression for a cubic equation I cannot reproduce. This equation, when you solve this, results into the correct numerical values for the roots of the cubic.
The equations are:
\begin{align*} x^3-3x+2a = 0\\3x^2\frac{dx}{da}-3\frac{dx}{da}+2=0 \end{align*}
Eliminating $x$ leads to :
$$\left(a^2-1\right)\left(3\frac{dx}{da}\right)^3+9\frac{dx}{da}+2=0$$
Can anybody derive this last expression from the first two?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! In the future, try to use MathJax to type math (it's pretty much LaTeX if you're familiar with that).

Comment: Hint: write the first equation as $x(x^2-3) = -2a$, square, then substitute $x^2$ from the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my previous [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727616/derivating-a-polynomial-equation-from-two-others#comment10019548_4727616), let $\,\dfrac{dx}{da} = t\,$ then the problem is to eliminate $\,x\,$ between:

$$
\begin{align}
x^3 - 3x + 2a = 0
\\ 3t\, x^2 - 3 t + 2=0
\end{align}
$$

Writing the first equation as $\,- 2 a = x(x^2 - 3)\,$, squaring, and substituting $\,x^2 = 1 - \dfrac{2}{3t}\,$ from the second equation:

$$
4a^2 = x^2(x^2-3)^2 = \left(1 - \dfrac{2}{3t}\right)\left(-2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{3t}\right)\right)^2 = \ldots = \frac{4(27 t^3 - 9 t - 2)}{27 t^3}
$$
$$
\implies\quad 27(a^2 - 1) t^3 + 9 t + 2 = 0
$$

Remembering that $\,t = \dfrac{dx}{da}\,$, the latter is OP's third equation.

Comment: Or, with the help of a CAS, use the polynomial [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) e.g. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28x%5E3+-+3+x+%2B+2+a%2C+3+t+x%5E2+-+3+t+%2B+2%2C+x%29).

Answer (score 0):

From the second equation, you have $$\frac{dx}{da}=\frac{2}{3(1-x^2)}\implies \left(3\frac{dx}{da}\right)^3=\frac{8}{(1-x^2)^3}$$

Therefore, $$\left(a^2-1\right)\left(3\frac{dx}{da}\right)^3+9\frac{dx}{da}=\frac{8(a^2-1)}{(1-x^2)^3}+\frac{6}{1-x^2}$$

Meanwhile, from the first equation, $$8a^2=2x^2(3-x^2)^2$$

So if you substitute this into the expression above and simplify the fraction on the right hand side, you get $$\frac{2x^6-6x^4+6x^2-2}{(1-x^2)^3}=-2,$$ thus establishing the third equation

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You proved that the third equation is correct. But I still wonder how the third equation was found by mr. Cockle, thus how it was derived from the first two equations, if you don't know anything about this third equation. PS I tried the suggestion of dxiv, but I did not obtain equation 3.

Answer (score 0):

From

$$
3x^2\frac{dx}{da}-3\frac{dx}{da}+2=0\Rightarrow 3x^3\frac{dx}{da}-3x\frac{dx}{da}+2x=0
$$

and then

$$
3(3x-2a)\frac{dx}{da}-3x\frac{dx}{da}+2x=0\Rightarrow 6x\frac{dx}{da}-6a\frac{dx}{da}+2x=0
$$

now eliminating $x$ between

$$
\cases{
x^3-3x+2a=0\\
6x\frac{dx}{da}-6a\frac{dx}{da}+2x=0
}
$$

we get

$$
a\left(\left(a^2-1\right) \left(3\frac{dx}{da}\right)^3+9 \frac{dx}{da}+2\right)=0
$$